# nginx - Is there a CLI tool for editing the configuration file?

Tags: configuration, nginx, command-line-interface

For example, I'd like to set a new or remove a virtual host in the `nginx.conf` configuration file without editing it directly but using a command-line tool, like:

```
nginx-cli add-server [options]
nginx-cli remove-server [options]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if either of these will exactly fill your need, but they both offer some tools for `nginx`

- [Nginx VHost Tools](https://github.com/caius/nginx-vhost-tools) includes a tool for generating and saving a `nginx` config file, which might help.
- [Nginx Tools](https://github.com/lovette/nginx-tools) has a tool for managing sites as well as minifying config files.  Probably not what you're looking for, but you may the source helpful.